# Writing unicode C++ source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, internationalization

I saw on the project properties on Visual Studio 2012 that you can select the Character set for your application.

I use Unicode Character set.
What is the problem with Multi-byte character set? Or better, why should I use the Unicode?

Take for example this piece of code from a DLL that I am doing

```
RECORD_API int startRecording(
   char *cam_name,      // Friendly video device name
   char *time,          // Max time for recording
   char *f_width,       // Frame width
   char *f_height,      // Frame height
   char *file_path)     // Complete output file path
{
  ...
}
```

A lot of Unicode functions from Windows.h header use wchar_t parameters; should I use wchar_t also for my functions parameters?

Should I always explicit the W functions (example: ShellExecuteW) ?

Comment: Read http://utf8everywhere.org about how to do unicode properly on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, regardless of what the interface says, the question isn't
Unicode or not, but UTF-16 or UTF-8.  Practically speaking, for
external data, you should only use UTF-8.  Internally, it
depends on what you are doing.  Conversion of UTF-8 to UTF-16 is
an added complication, but for more complex operations, it may
be easier to work in UTF-16.  (Although the differences between
UTF-8 and UTF-16 aren't enormous.  To reap any real benefits,
you'd have to use UTF-32, and even then...)

In practice, I would avoid the W functions completely, and
always use `char const*` at the system interface level.  But
again, it depends on what you are doing.  This is just a general
guideline.  For the rest, I'd stick with `std::string` *unless*
there was some strong reason not to.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `A` functions don't support UTF-8, so if you want proper Unicode support, you *must* call the `W` functions.

Comment: @dan04 Funny, because I use the A functions all the time with UTF-8.

Comment: Win32 API `A` functions most definitely DO NOT support UTF-8.  You can **pass** UTF-8 data in `char*` parameters, but the API will not **interpret** such data as UTF-8. ASCII-only strings will work, since UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII, but non-ASCII characters require extra processing that the API simply does not do on `char*` data. Most `A` functions simply delegate to `W` functions, using `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` internally as needed, but the codepage used is the OS default Ansi codepage as configured in the Control Panel, not user-defined in code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In most cases, the function doesn't interpret the data at all; it just passes it through.  When it interprets it, it looks for specific characters (like '/' or '\') which are all single byte characters.  There are specific cases where you have to pay attention, but they are the exception.

Comment: @JamesKanze: An `A` function converts `char` input data to `wchar_t` using `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP)`, then calls the corresponding `W` function, then converts `wchar_t` output data to `char` using `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP)`. If the input contains non-ASCII characters that are not encoded as CP_ACP (including UTF-8), they will be lost/damaged during that conversion. Any output will never be encoded as UTF-8 regardless. So **DO NOT** pass UTF-8 non-ASCII data to `A` functions, unless you don't care about data loss.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is simply false.  It may do the conversion for specific internal data (like filenames---but you don't put non-ASCII characters in a filename anyway), but I regularly write UTF-8 and other binary data to files using `WriteFile`, for example, with no problems.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  `WriteFile()` does not have `A` and `W` variants, since it operates on raw binary data, not on text data. Everything I have described is true for text-based API functions that actually do have `A` and `W` variants. And BTW, file names and paths **CAN** have non-ASCII characters in them. Ever see a Japanese user's file system? I have. They love using non-ASCII Unicode characters in their folder/file names, and they work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly call, the `..W` version of a function as this should already be covered by the include files and the settings that you use. So if you compile for Unicodesupport, then the `W` version of your system call will be used, otherwise the `A`.

Personally I would only compile for Unicode if you can really test it. At least you shouldn't assume that your application really can work properly in all cases, just because you compiled for it. Compiling for it is only the first step, but of course, you must consequently use the appropriate types and test your code, to be sure that there are no effects you may not have noticed.